# Textarea scroll doesn't fire if keyboard is active on Android Chrome

Tags: android, html, css, google-chrome

I have a long webpage that scrolls down. There are some textareas lower down in
the page.

I open the webpage in Chrome for Android, scroll down, and tap on a textarea,
then try to scroll the textarea.

When I try to scroll, the textarea does not scroll and does not receive the
scroll event.

I can still scroll other, non-focused, textareas, but not the currently focused
one.

Here's the webpage I'm using.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

    <style>
        body {
            margin: 24rem auto;
            max-width: 512px;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
        }
        textarea {
            display: block;
            flex-grow: 1;
            padding: 1rem;
            margin: 3rem 1rem;
        }

        #info {
            display: flex;
            column-gap: 1rem;
        }
    </style>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

    <script>
        let i = 0;
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
            window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
                const info = document.getElementById("info-win");
                info.textContent = `win ${i++}`;
            });
            document.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
                const info = document.getElementById("info-body");
                info.textContent = `doc ${i++}`;
            });

            document.getElementById("ta1").addEventListener("scroll", function() {
                const info = document.getElementById("info-ta1");
                info.textContent = `ta1 ${i++}`;
            });
            document.getElementById("ta2").addEventListener("scroll", function() {
                const info = document.getElementById("info-ta2");
                info.textContent = `ta2 ${i++}`;
            });
            document.getElementById("ta3").addEventListener("scroll", function() {
                const info = document.getElementById("info-ta3");
                info.textContent = `ta3 ${i++}`;
            });
        });
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <textarea id="ta1">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas in
    dignissim elit. Duis iaculis eleifend porta. Morbi rutrum non urna non
    venenatis. Aliquam nibh ante, porttitor eu sodales at, tincidunt eget
    tortor. Donec efficitur neque ante, non pharetra est finibus non. Praesent
    eu porttitor tortor. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per
    conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Suspendisse efficitur facilisis
    hendrerit. Nunc faucibus mollis dignissim. Ut lobortis ullamcorper tortor,
    ac varius sapien vehicula sed.
    </textarea>

    <div id="info">
        <p id="info-win"></p>
        <p id="info-body"></p>
        <p id="info-ta1"></p>
        <p id="info-ta2"></p>
        <p id="info-ta3"></p>
    </div>

    <textarea id="ta2">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas in
    dignissim elit. Duis iaculis eleifend porta. Morbi rutrum non urna non
    venenatis. Aliquam nibh ante, porttitor eu sodales at, tincidunt eget
    tortor. Donec efficitur neque ante, non pharetra est finibus non. Praesent
    eu porttitor tortor. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per
    conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Suspendisse efficitur facilisis
    hendrerit. Nunc faucibus mollis dignissim. Ut lobortis ullamcorper tortor,
    ac varius sapien vehicula sed.
    </textarea>

    <textarea id="ta3">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas in
    dignissim elit. Duis iaculis eleifend porta. Morbi rutrum non urna non
    venenatis. Aliquam nibh ante, porttitor eu sodales at, tincidunt eget
    tortor. Donec efficitur neque ante, non pharetra est finibus non. Praesent
    eu porttitor tortor. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per
    conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Suspendisse efficitur facilisis
    hendrerit. Nunc faucibus mollis dignissim. Ut lobortis ullamcorper tortor,
    ac varius sapien vehicula sed.
    </textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

Chrome for Android version: 122.0.6261.199

I also tested on Firefox for Android and the textarea scrolls fine.

Is there a way I can workaround this behavior in Chrome for Android?